Power automate sender’s name displayed wrong
When sending emails by power automate via Gmail, the senders name displayed “info” all the time, however if I were sending mails from Gmail account directly, the name displayed correctly, how to make power automate to use my correct sender name like in Gmail

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
